# Array key name mapping in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am really getting stuck in renaming an array using a mapping array in PHP. I am able to pick and change the name of elements which has string or int content. But really getting messed up with a nested array.

Mapping array:

```
$source = array(
    'id'   =>   ['keys' => ['app_id'], 'type' => 'int'],
    'name' =>   ['keys' => ['app_name'], 'type' => 'string'],
    'proj' =>   [
        'general'   => ['keys' => ['project', 'gen'], 'type' => 'string'],
        'category'  => ['keys' => ['project', 'cat'], 'type' => 'string']
    ]
);
```

Before transforming:

```
$post = array(
    'id' => 1000,
    'name' => 'API sample',
    'proj' => array(
        'general'  => 10,
        'category' => 50
    ) 
);
```

Desired output:

```
$result = array(
    'app_id' => 1000,
    'app_name' => 'API sample',
    'project' => array(
        'gen'  => 10,
        'cat' => 50
    ) 
);
```

Code:

```
   function renameArray($mappings,$inputObjectDb) {
        $inputObjectDb = (array)$inputObjectDb;
        $response = [];
        foreach($mappings as $key => $mapping) {
            //call itself in order to prepare sub array
            if(!isset($mapping['keys'])) {
                $response[$key] = prepareOutputData($mapping,$inputObjectDb);
            } else {
                $dbSubarray = $inputObjectDb;
                foreach( $mapping['keys'] as $subkey) {
                    $response[$key] = $dbSubarray[$subkey];
                    $dbSubarray = &$dbSubarray[$subkey];
                }
            }

        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Based on your example: `$result['project'][$source['proj']['general']['keys'][1]] = 10;`

Comment: This is less simple than you might think.  You basically need a _recursive_ function.  Show us what you've attempted so far.

Comment: `['app_name'], 'type' => 'int'],` => `API sample` Is that error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($source as $k=>$v) {
        if(!is_array($post[$k]))
                $ret[$v['keys'][0]] = $post[$k];
        else {
                foreach($v as $kk=>$vv)
                        $ret[$vv['keys'][0]][$vv['keys'][1]] = $post[$k][$kk];
        }
}

print_r($ret);
```

The final output of this will be stored in `$ret`.

Variables that I'll use bellow:

- `$k` - will refer to the key of `$source` in the current iteration
- `$v` - will refer to the array associated at `$source[$k]`
- `$kk` - will refer to the key of `$v` in the current iteration
- `$vv` - will refer to the array associated at `$v[$kk]`

Firstly, we loop over the elements of `$source`. Inside we have two options:

- `$post[$k]` holds value(not array). In this case, we build an element for `$ret`. The key will use `$v['keys'][0]`(the first element of the `keys` array in `$v`). The value will use the data from `$post[$k]`.
- `$post[$k]` is an array. In this case we will iterate over `$v`. In each iteration we build an array element for `$ret`. The array key will be `$vv['keys'][0]`(the first element of the `keys` array of `$vv`. The element of `$vv['keys'][0]` will have a key that will be `$vv['keys'][1]`(the second element of `keys` array of `$vv`). The value for `$vv['keys'][1]` will be `$post[$k][$kk]`.

Comment: None of the variable names are all that useful.  Descriptive variable names are better.  Rather than `$k => $v`, why not `$key => $attributes`, and instead of `$kk => $vv`, `$sub_key => $sub_attributes` (just for example).

Comment: What is a useful variable name? _The best code communicates itself_: https://medium.com/mindorks/meaningful-names-a-dimension-of-writing-clean-code-fdae1ae4f0b1 and http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203618/how-to-name-variables

Comment: **I am just trying to help you** be a better coder.  Do what you want with the tips.  I've learned a LOT from other developers on this site.  If you are willing to listen / receive input, you can too.  Or, you can be a smart-aleck and reject the feedback that other developers offer.  Up to you.