# Unable to write the ICMP response into excel

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, scapy

I am trying to write the response received for ICMP query into excel sheet
  below is the sample code

```
from scapy.layers.inet import *
a1= IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP()
a = sr1(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP(), iface="Wireless Network Connection", timeout=10)
b = a.summary()

# Create file workbook and worksheet
outworkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
outsheet = outworkbook.add_worksheet()

# writing headers
outsheet.write("A1", "Requests")
outsheet.write("B1", "Response")

 # writing data
 outsheet.write("A2", a1)
 outsheet.write("B2", b)
```

created excel has only headers and the response value is not written
I tried few other things as well, but nothing worked so far
Any idea whats wrong with this code?

Comment: If you try printing out the data before writing to the excel file, do you see it?

Comment: Yes i can see the data (output is --> IP / ICMP 192.168.1.10 > 192.168.1.1 echo-request 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problems

You have 5 problems that I can see:

1. You're not importing `xlsxwriter`. This is important for this to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
2. The last 2 writes are indented one space (Python cares about this).
3. You aren't closing the workbook so the file isn't being saved.
4. Vars `a`, `a1`, and `b` should be more descriptive ([this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203648/1596750) demonstrates why)
5. You build a packet named a1 (renamed `ping`) and then build it again on the next line

#### Solution

The fixed code looks like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter
from scapy.layers.inet import *

# My firewall is at 192.168.1.254 so use that address; en0 is my interface
ping_packet = IP(dst="192.168.1.254")/ICMP()
answer = sr1(ping_packet, iface="en0", timeout=10)
ping_summary = answer.summary()

# Create file workbook and worksheet
outworkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
outsheet = outworkbook.add_worksheet()

# writing headers
outsheet.write("A1", "Requests")
outsheet.write("B1", "Response")

# writing data
outsheet.write("A2", a1)
outsheet.write("B2", b)

# close file
outworkbook.close()
```

#### Verification

Opening this in Libreoffice, we see that it has been saved: [image: Libreoffice Spreadsheet]

Comment: Thanks Jacobs, code which i shared here was for demo purpose,I agree it should have written little better.However what worked for me was adding a delay of 5 sec , after that i can see the response in excel

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere:) You may want to add an edit section to your question for what worked for you, for the benefit of future readers.